# Does a what-links-here report for Gollum exist?

Tags: github, wiki, gollum-wiki

Is there any existing way to generate a **what-links-here** report for a [gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum) wiki?  In other words, a list of the pages within the same wiki that link to the current page: **a list of the local inbound links**.

I wasn't able to spot any feature like this, nor find anything suitable in the API, but I may have missed it.  Is there a third party add-on for it?

I do understand the reason it probably doesn't exist in the core: as these are plain text files, there isn't any table of links maintained anywhere.  For the same reason, when a page is renamed it breaks all the inbound links to that page from other pages.

A function for this could use the API to read the generated source of each page (so that only html with normalized names needs to be parsed), producing a list of the local links from each page and the page they are on. Cache the results at page level until the next commit of that page.

This could be used to enhance the existing page rename feature as well.  Has anybody already done this?